# How to access response json object in "PowerApp Canvas" without adding response sample to the connector?

Tags: powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, power-automate-custom-connector

I have a "customer api" to get profile infromation by ID.
A custom connector is created using this api.
Then the Connector is used in Canvas Power App.

Within the app data is stored in collection named "DataReceived".

Issue is:
if we don't add sample response body while creating custom connector, data in collection is a Boolean value as shown in the image 1.

But if we add sample response, we could access all the information which matches the sample schema. Data stored in collection is tabular as shown in image 2.

Image 1:

### [image: Canvas Power App "Collection" when "response sample is not added" to the customs collector]

Image 2: canvas Power App "Collection" when "response sample is added" to the customs collector

[image: Canvas Power App "Collection" when "response sample is added" to the customs collector]

So the main issue is:
Is there a way to access json data in powerapps(canvas) collection without adding "sample response" in the "custom connector"?

Comment: I guess azure-api-management tag does not apply here or did I miss something? It is pure powerapps, right? -Thanks

Comment: No. It's pure powerapps.